# How to save the Constraint Layout as an image with full resolution?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, android-bitmap

I am saving the layout as a bitmap, but after saving the resolution and the size of the image reduces too much. So how can I save it high resolution and size?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compress the image in PNG with the high quality?

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried that but it doesn't seems to work. An image with size 7 mb is been reduced to around 50 kb.